# `HISTSIZE=-1` causes 100% CPU on MacBook. Why does this happened?

Tags: bash

I am setting up my first MacBook. I copied by `.bash_aliases` file from my Linux Mint. After that, I can not open Terminal with a bash session. I just see a black screen and bash taking 100% of my CPU.

I found that the problem is `HISTSIZE=-1`

Why does bash fall into an infinite loop? And how do I allow unlimited history?

Comment: First, are you certain you’re in Bash and not Zsh?  By “first” MacBook, I’m assuming new or new-ish.  The default shell is now Zsh.  Secondly, (if I remember correctly) you can have an “unlimited” history by unsetting the value, not setting it negative.

Comment: @Allan From bash(1): "If the value is 0, commands are not saved in the history list.  Numeric values less than zero result in every command being saved on the history list (there is no limit). The shell sets the default value to 500 after reading any startup files."

Comment: Sorry, I meant set to null which is different from  unsetting. The most likely cause of the system slowness is Bash reading a super huge history file consuming system resources.  The OP should try pruning old history entries

Comment: @Allan: I switched it from zsh to bash: `echo $SHELL` (/bin/bash). There is no old history at all. This is a new MacBook.

Comment: So, just to confirm, you didn’t copy over any of the dot files from Mint to your Mac other than the aliases?    How big/small is your history file size?

Comment: @Allan: I copied `.inputrc`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases`. I removed all not required content from them. Also I tested that 100% CPU usage was caused only by `HISTSIZE=-1` line. When I comment it out, all works as expected. When I asked the question the `.bash_history` file does not exists at all. As of now it is 70 bytes. Yes, only couple of commands there.

Comment: `HISTSIZE` with values less than zero are applicable to Bash 4 and above. If you look at the man page on your machine (`man bash`) you see it makes no reference to this (v3.2), but the [current Bash version (v5.2) does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTSIZE). You were probably using a newer Bash on Mint.  If you update Bash, it should work fine.

Comment: @Allan: `$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>`

Comment: In comments, you said you’re using `/bin/bash` which is included with macOS.  [That version is 3.2](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/bash/tree/bash-131). What you got with `echo $SHELL`.   If you have Bash 5.2 installed, you need to change the user shell (`chsh`) to the version/location where you updated it (Homebrew, I’m guessing?).

Comment: @Allan: I understand my error. `/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash` Thank you, Allan

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Allan. The problem was with an old bash version. v3.2 does not support yet `HISTSIZE=-1`.

So I allow my new bash `echo '/usr/local/bin/bash' >> /etc/shells`. (otherwise I got error: `chsh: /usr/local/bin/bash: non-standard shell`.

And then changed the shell to it:
`chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: Glad you were able to get it sorted!  +1