# Mac M2 default terminal in VSCode not working as expected

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line

Step by step:

In VSCode I've set the default terminal (`Command + Shift + P` -> `>Terminal: Select Default Profile`) to `bash` (`/bin/bash`).

Close all terminals, open a new one (`` Control + Shift + ` ``) and while I can see `bash` at the top right of the VSCode terminal panel, the text shown inside of the terminal itself says:

```sh
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Which is itself contradictory.

Just in case I ran `chsh -s /bin/bash`
and it answers `Changing shell for myUserName`, asks for my password, proceed and changes done.

Close the terminal, open a new one and again:

```sh
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Now if I try to run `chsh -s /bin/bash` it answers `chsh: no changes made`, "good" -I thought-

One would assume that it should be `bash` then, but if I run `git --version` I get

```sh
git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
```

This is important because I've set the path to the homebrew installed git to the `~/.bashrc` and it's not working even though `chsh` and VSCode panel are telling me this is `bash`...

Now if I run `/bin/bash` see:

```sh
$ /bin/bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

bash-3.2$ git --version
git version 2.41.0
```

I've double-checked on the system preferences (`apple symbol` -> `System Settings` -> `Users & Groups` -> `^myUserName` -> `Advanced Settings` -> `Login Shell`) and it's `/bin/bash`

I'm completely out of ideas at this moment, any clue on why this is happening and how to solve/overcome? Thanks

Comment: I assume that suppressing the message won't make my default terminal to effectively be /bin/bash...

Comment: It's just an informational message that Zsh is the default shell (since Catalina).  It doesn't affect anything.  Suppressing the message does just and only that...suppress the message.

Comment: Completely agree, but my goal is to effectively use /bin/bash despite what apple wants and by default (no /bin/bash each time I open a terminal).

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem: "I can see bash at the top right of the VSCode terminal panel, the text shown inside of the terminal itself says:" -> so you are running bash already (the text is just a reminder to switch to zsh).

Comment: how's then the git version different from running it straight away after opening the terminal from when I type /bin/bash and then git -v? The path config for the brew installed git is set to ~/.bashrc, so in my head it's using zsh even though I configured bash everywhere.

Comment: `/bin/bash` is the version of Bash (3.2) that shipped with macOS.  You need to change your shell to the Homebrew version.  See [this related answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462286/119271) on how to do this.  Again, what you're seeing is informational, not a failure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction Allan

Comment: @JoelBonetR VSCode is most likely running a login shell. `~/.bashrc` is not executed by login shells. Refer to the INVOCATION section of the man page.